# How to avoid the double deletion?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, delete-operator

Can someone why the double deletion here, and how I can avoid this crash?  The crash only occurs when the program is exited.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <conio.h>

struct State;

struct FlyweightStates {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<State>> prototypes;
    static void insertPrototype (const std::string& tag, State* state) {
        prototypes.emplace(tag, std::shared_ptr<State>(state));
        std::cout << tag << " inserted in FlyweightStates::prototypes." << std::endl;
    }
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<State>> FlyweightStates::prototypes;

struct State {
    virtual ~State() {std::cout << "State destructor called." << std::endl;  _getch();}
    State (const std::string& name) {
        FlyweightStates::insertPrototype(name, this);
    }
};

struct Sleeping : public State {
    static Sleeping prototype;
    Sleeping() : State("Sleeping") {}
};
Sleeping Sleeping::prototype;

int main() {}
```

Also crashes is the following:

```
struct FlyweightStates {
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<State>> prototypes;
    static void insertPrototype (const std::string& tag, std::shared_ptr<State> state) {
        prototypes.emplace(tag, state);
        std::cout << tag << " inserted in FlyweightStates::prototypes." << std::endl;
    }
};
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<State>> FlyweightStates::prototypes;

struct State {
    virtual ~State() {std::cout << "State destructor called." << std::endl;  _getch();}
    State (const std::string& stateName) {
        FlyweightStates::insertPrototype (stateName, std::shared_ptr<State>(this));
    }
};
```

What can I do to avoid the double deletion?  I cannot use shared_from_this().  I need shared_ptrs in the flyweight storage.

Comment: That's a ton of code with no indication what fails or where it fails. Please provide more details.

Comment: The crash only occurs when the program is exited.

Comment: @nvoigt That is a complete example. [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec05e67ebd3cdcf4)

Comment: The double destruction is because you're creating a `shared_ptr` from a pointer to a static object. Perhaps you could use a blank deleter in that case; or dynamically allocate the static instance; or restructure the flyweight manager to create objects itself rather than (very dangerously) accepting raw pointers to objects it hopes were created with `new`.

Comment: @Mike.  I've never used a deleter other than the default.  How do I construct a blank deleter?

Comment: @prestokeys: I'd use a lambda that does nothing, `[](void*){}`.

Comment: @Mike.  FlyweightStates::insertPrototype (stateName, std::shared_ptr<State>(this, [](void*){})); solved the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeSeymour what's the point of using `shared_ptr` at all in this case. And blank deleter will cause memory leak in case of dynamically allocated object

Comment: @AntonSavin: Because the flyweight manager works with shared pointers, so you need a shared pointer. Obviously, you'd only use a blank deleter for static objects like this one, and the default deleter for dynamic ones.

Comment: The flyweight manager works with State objects that are shared_ptrs everywhere in my program, so it should store States in the form shared_ptr.

Answer (score 4):

[The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed, ...](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

So one invocation of the destructor occurs when the `shared_ptr` is being destroyed.
And another time destructor is invoked when C++ runtime destroys `static Sleeping prototype;`.

The program crashes because the destructor of `shared_ptr` tries to delete the pointer which was not allocated on the heap.

**What to do**
If `prototypes` is going to contain only static objects like in your code, then there's no need to use `shared_ptr` at all, because these objects will be deleted automatically when program exits. Declare `prototypes` just as

```
static std::unordered_map<std::string, State*> prototypes;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4308a827b1d3b21b)

If `prototypes` can contain both static and dynamic objects, it means that it can contain *only* dynamic objects, so make `Sleeping::prototype` a `shared_ptr` as well:

```
static std::shared_ptr<Sleeping> prototype;
...
std::shared_ptr<Sleeping> Sleeping::prototype(new Sleeping());
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/978e27250a5bb028)

Also, if you use `shared_ptr<State>` throughout your code, I would advise to make a typedef for it, so you can easily change it to `State*` or whatever else pointer type you want.

Comment: My entire program uses State objects with shared_ptr, so are you sure it is safe to store the prototype states in the form of raw pointers?

Comment: @prestokeys If the objects have static storage duration like in your code, then yes, raw pointers are fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with a `shared_ptr`, you should create it immediately from the raw pointer and then ignore the raw pointer from that point forward. If you create a *second* `shared_ptr` using the same raw pointer, you'll get a second delete. You should also not delete the raw pointer yourself.

Unfortunately you haven't shown enough code to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The crash only occurs when the program is exited.  So there are two owners that both think they own the pointer, but how do I avoid this?  I cannot use shared_from_this().

Answer (score 0):

The program destructs the same `State` in the map and the static variable the end of the program.

But the real problem is that your state is a static variable, and you pass its address to a `shared_ptr`. And the end of its lifetime, `shared_ptr` not only call the destructor of the object but also tries to free the pointer it got. But your object is in the static storage and freeing an object in the static storage area is invalid.

Take away 1: do not pass objects not created with `new` to a `shared_ptr`.

Take away 2: use [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) to create a shared pointer.

Comment: On the stack? Really?